# Is it possible to transfer / associate local administrator account to / with a new Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-8, user-profiles

Since 2004 I'm using same local Administrator profile.
So far, I kept the account and its settings using wizards for every new upgrade.
Respectively, Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 without problem and now Windows 8 (Pro).
I realized new modern apps (it's already charm of the windows 8) runs in a sandbox which cannot be run under local administrator account.
I have alot of settings made ​​in the last 9 years and I don't want to lose them.
Can I transfer all my local user settings to a new Microsoft account without loss.
Or an association between two accounts would be greatful but it seems not possible AFAIK.
BTW I've never used BitLocker or something like to encrypt my profile.
Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, this is an interesting question. I'd have to say 'yes', but it would take some work on your part.

1)Rename the profile to something other than 'Administrator'.

2)Use either the built in 'Windows Easy Transfer' tool in Win 7 and transfer it to Win 8, or the (if you like the cmd prompt) Microsoft USMT tool http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801(v=ws.10).aspx which does the same thing but is geared for large corporations with tons of users to migrate.